# Adding comment using react and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to build a website where users can comment on a given post. i want to display comment when Button is pressed. All work fine, but i want to show/hide comment when i click comment button. I'm using comment button inside map function so all the elements are executing it. how to show/hide comment for individual element? Please Help.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {this.state.queries.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <div key={key}>
            <hr />

            <div className="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary row ">
              <div className="authorName">{item.name}</div>
              <div>{item.description}</div>
              <hr />
              <div>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-info"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#demo"
                  onClick={() => {
                    return fetch("/queries/" + item._id)
                      .then(Response => Response.json())
                      .then(data => {
                        this.setState({ comment: data.comments });
                      });
                  }}
                >
                  Comment
                </button>
                <div id="demo" className="collapse">
                  <br />
                  <form
                    className="commentForm"
                    action={"http://localhost:5000/queries/" + item._id}
                    method="POST"
                  >
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Write a comment..."
                      name="comment"
                    />

                    <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                      Post
                    </button>
                  </form>
                  <br />
                  <div>
                    {this.state.comment.map((commentItem, key) => {
                      return (
                        <div className="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                          <span className="authorName">
                            {commentItem.author}
                          </span>
                          {commentItem.text}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

JSONfrom server at 'localhost:5000/queries/'+item._id

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "_id": "5b5eadeeb415381598bdc825",
      "text": "sfsdfsd",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b5ecbe5b415381598bdc827",
      "text": "hii from alex",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b5ecd9ed8f72736c830a311",
      "text": "asdad",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "_id": "5b5ea97f7fb6e02d58b80dba",
  "name": "ram@gmail.com",
  "description": "Is axios still in use?",
  "__v": 3
}
```

Comment: Which button click should hide which elements? I can see at least 2 buttons, 2 map statements.

Comment: first one with button named comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would highly recommend reading the [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) part of react documentation. You are facing these problems because you are not leveraging/using the power of encapsulation that React components bring.

**Root Cause**: You have multiple places where you can show comments, however you are maintaining them in a *single* state, so one will always override for others.

From looking at your code, it looks like you may be aiming for the following structure:

```
Container -
    - Posts
        - Comments
```

Container would be responsible for showing all the "posts" --> `this.state.queries.map` functionality.

Each `Post` can be responsible for rendering its own comments. That way, even if you have multiple posts, each is responsible for their own comment section.

So your post component can look like:

```
class Post extends React.Component{
  state = {
     comments: []
  }

  render() {

    let {item, key} = this.props;
    return (<div key={key}>
            <hr />

            <div className="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary row ">
              <div className="authorName">{item.name}</div>
              <div>{item.description}</div>
              <hr />
              <div>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-info"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#demo"
                  onClick={() => {
                    return fetch("/queries/" + item._id)
                      .then(Response => Response.json())
                      .then(data => {
                        this.setState({ comment: data.comments });
                      });
                  }}
                >
                  Comment
                </button>
                <div id="demo" className="collapse">
                  <br />
                  <form
                    className="commentForm"
                    action={"http://localhost:5000/queries/" + item._id}
                    method="POST"
                  >
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      placeholder="Write a comment..."
                      name="comment"
                    />

                    <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                      Post
                    </button>
                  </form>
                  <br />
                  <div>
                    {this.state.comment.map((commentItem, key) => {
                      return (
                        <div className="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                          <span className="authorName">
                            {commentItem.author}
                          </span>
                          {commentItem.text}
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>)
}
```

And your Container can be:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {this.state.queries.map((item, key) => {
        return (<Post item={item} key={key} />)
```

Comment: yes thanks alot dubes. Can you help me out with the comment button collapse. i've defined button collapse id just below the comment button. so all the post opens up the comment. where should i put that?

Comment: I see that your `Comments` component should've the following state: {showComments: false, comments: []} then you can have 2 methods: 1 to fetch comments and one to show/hide the comments. I highly recommend reading the "conditional rendering" and "state and props" of the official documentation